# Sending pdf to node/express backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm trying to send pdf file form client to node/express backend. The file is generated via jsPDF. The request looks like that:

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "http://localhost:7000/test",
   type: "POST",
   data: {
     pdfFile
   },
   crossDomain: true,
   contentType: "application/pdf",
   success: function(){
     console.log('success');
   },
   error: function(){
     alert('Unable to send to the server');
   }
 })
```

All I need is to check if the backend is getting it. I've tried with express-fileupload but with no luck:

```
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload');

module.exports = app => {
  app.post("/test", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.files);
    res.end();
  })
};
```

All I need to achieve is to make sure that the file is send correctly from client and received by backend.